# Multiple border color with CSS

Tags: css, html

I want to make multiple lines border in CSS, each line in different color placed on top of each other, without using a background image?

See sample below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/Juli15/CdWCA/176/) which shows you how to work with the [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo-elements.

```css
body {
  margin: 2em;
}

.TopBorder {
  border-top: 2px solid #36db8b;
  position: relative;
}

.TopBorder::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  top: -2px;
  border-top: 2px solid #cccccc;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="TopBorder ">

  Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
  placerat eleifend leo.

</div>
```

So you can have two styles for one element, just one as normal (the first part of the border with `::before`) and then the other one added after (obviously with `::after`).